# as props issue in Next.js Link Component (App Router)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

So I am building some pages in the App router, but I don't understand the as props behaviour, for example I use the Link component like below on a dynamic route:

```
      {
        datas.map((project) => {
          return (
            <div key={project.id}>  
              <Link
                href={`/projects/${project.id}`}
                as={`/projects/${project.title}}
              >
                {project.description}
              </Link>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
```

I was expecting to get a more friendly Url on the browser instead of a serie of number from id, and yea I can see the expected url displayed on the browser, however I am not getting the id from the real path coming from the href props. (therefore I get an error since the url with title is not found)

when i check the console i am getting the title name and not the id from href, the situaiton is like href is being ignored by the Link Component when as props exist, if i removed as props, I will get the right id in the params, so did I misunderstood the real purpose from the as props or I am doing something wrong ?